# OpenGL flip or mirror the drawing object

Tags: opengl

How can i flip, ot mirror up/left of the image OBJECT, not the screen in the onDraw method?

I tried scale(1, -1, 1) that not worked

my code:

```
 opengl.selectVertex(vertexname)
                                .translate(x-1, y, -9);

                                if (opengl.getPathModifier(vertexname).getAngle()>-180 && 
                                    opengl.getPathModifier(vertexname).getAngle()<0 ) {
                                    opengl.selectVertex(vertexname).scale(-scale,scale,1);  
                                } else {
                                    opengl.selectVertex(vertexname).scale(scale,scale,1);
                                }

opengl.rotate(opengl.getPathModifier(vertexname).getAngle()+90, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Do you want to flip in the x direction, the y direction or both?

Comment: Please clarify what kind of flip you want.

Comment: Do you have culling enabled? If so, transforming via scale(1, -1, 1) will result in all your triangles drawn in the opposite order. You need to temporarily reverse/disable your winding when you draw the reflection.

Comment: culling was the probleme:D if u make an answer then i will accept it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're asking here, but I think what you want to do is transform the projection matrix. If you want to flip so that things on the left appear on the right then you need to Scale the projection matrix by (-1, 1, 1). If you want things at the top to appear at the bottom you need to scale by (1,-1, 1) and if you want both you can scale (-1, -1, 1).

Edit based on extra information: If all you want to do is display the object exactly the same, but with texture flipped, you need to change the texture coordinates of the vertices in the objects - flip the texture coordinates by replacing the old u texture coordinate with 1-u.

Comment: i am in glPerspective, so not in ortho, if i use scale(-1,1,1) then i cant see my object, why?

Comment: I have to change my texture coordinates when my rotate angle changes? is there a simple algorithm to change my texture coords in my vertex?

Comment: @lacas: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an "airplane" i rotate my plane, but after 180 degrees my plane turning around... on head

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is incrementally rotate the object using a rotation transform on the ModelView matrix. E.g. rotate the object 5 degrees per frame around the Z axis. This should fix your problem and simplify your code.

Comment: Flipping texture coordinates _u_ to _1-u_ will only work if your texture contains a single sprite. If you're using a sprite atlas, your calculations will be different.

Comment: How do you flipV or flipH a sub image of an atlas, if you are just croping the source image using vertices data rather than copying the image using glTexSubImage2D? Scaling or rotating the matrix will rotate it around the source image's center. Is there any way to do it without creating copies?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `glFrustum(l,r,b,t,n,f)` then change it yo `glFrustum(l,r,t,b,n,f)`, in case you want a vertical flip. This apply also to `glOrtho` function.