# Vertically flipping an Char array: is there a more efficient way?

Tags: c++, image, performance, opengl

Lets start with some code:

```
QByteArray OpenGLWidget::modifyImage(QByteArray imageArray, const int width, const int height){
    if (vertFlip){
        /* Each pixel constist of four unisgned chars: Red Green Blue Alpha.
         * The field is normally 640*480, this means that the whole picture is in fact 640*4 uChars wide.
         * The whole ByteArray is onedimensional, this means that 640*4 is the red of the first pixel of the second row
         * This function is EXTREMELY SLOW
         */
        QByteArray tempArray = imageArray;
        for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h){
            for (int w = 0; w < width/2; ++w){
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
                    imageArray.data()[h*width*4 + 4*w + i] = tempArray.data()[h*width*4 + (4*width - 4*w) + i ];
                    imageArray.data()[h*width*4 + (4*width - 4*w) + i] = tempArray.data()[h*width*4 + 4*w + i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return imageArray;
}
```

This is the code I use right now to vertically flip an image which is 640*480 (The image is actually not guaranteed to be 640*480, but it mostly is). The color encoding is RGBA, which means that the total array size is 640*480*4. I get the images with 30 FPS, and I want to show them on the screen with the same FPS.

On an older CPU (Athlon x2) this code is just too much: the CPU is racing to keep up with the 30 FPS, so the question is: can I do this more efficient?

I am also working with OpenGL, does that have a gimmic I am not aware of that can flip images with relativly low CPU/GPU usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886561/opengl-flip-or-mirror-the-drawing-object), you can flip an image in OpenGL by scaling it by `(1,-1,1)`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360597/opengl-transformations-glscale-gltranslate-etc) explains how to do transformations and scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The actual solution was different: I wanted to invert the x-axis, so (-1,1,1) and after that I needed to move the image back into sight by using a translate: (-640,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

You can improve at least by doing it blockwise, making use of the cache architecture. In your example one of the accesses (either the read OR the write) will be off-cache.

Answer (score 0):

For a start it can help to "capture scanlines" if you're using two loops to loop through the pixels of an image, like so:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    // Capture scanline.
    char* scanline = imageArray.data() + y*width*4;

    for (int x = 0; x < width/2; ++x)
    {
        const int flipped_x = width - x-1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            swap(scanline[x*4 + i], scanline[flipped_x*4 + i]);
    }
}
```

Another thing to note is that I used `swap` instead of a temporary image. That'll tend to be more efficient since you can just swap using registers instead of loading pixels from a copy of the entire image.

But also it generally helps if you use a 32-bit integer instead of working one byte at a time if you're going to be doing anything like this. If you're working with pixels with 8-bit types but know that each pixel is 32-bits, e.g., as in your case, you can generally get away with a case to `uint32_t*`, e.g.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    uint32_t* scanline = (uint32_t*)imageArray.data() + y*width;
    std::reverse(scanline, scanline + width);
}
```

At this point you might parellelize the `y` loop. Flipping an image horizontally (it should be "horizontal" if I understood your original code correctly) in this way is a little bit tricky with the access patterns, but you should be able to get quite a decent boost using the above techniques.

> I am also working with OpenGL, does that have a gimmic I am not aware
>   of that can flip images with relativly low CPU/GPU usage?

Naturally the fastest way to flip images is to not touch their pixels at all and just save the flipping for the final part of the pipeline when you render the result. For this you might render a texture in OGL with negative scaling instead of modifying the pixels of a texture.

Another thing that's really useful in video and image processing is to represent an image to process like this for all your image operations:

```
struct Image32
{
     uint32_t* pixels;
     int32_t width;
     int32_t height;
     int32_t x_stride;
     int32_t y_stride;
};
```

The stride fields are what you use to get from one scanline (row) of an image to the next vertically and one column to the next horizontally. When you use this representation, you can use negative values for the stride and offset the pixels accordingly. You can also use the stride fields to, say, render only every other scanline of an image for fast interactive half-res scanline previews by using `y_stride=height*2` and `height/=2`. You can quarter-res an image by setting x stride to 2 and y stride to 2*width and then halving the width and height. You can render a cropped image without making your blit functions accept a boatload of parameters by just modifying these fields and keeping the y stride to width to get from one row of the cropped section of the image to the next:

```
// Using the stride representation of Image32, this can now
// blit a cropped source, a horizontally flipped source, 
// a vertically flipped source, a source flipped both ways,
// a half-res source, a quarter-res source, a quarter-res
// source that is horizontally flipped and cropped, etc,
// and all without modifying the source image in advance
// or having to accept all kinds of extra drawing parameters.
void blit(int dst_x, int dst_y, Image32 dst, Image32 src);

// We don't have to do things like this (and I think I lost
// some capabilities with this version below but it hurts my 
// brain too much to think about what capabilities were lost):
void blit_gross(int dst_x, int dst_y, int dst_w, int dst_h, uint32_t* dst, 
                int src_x, int src_y, int src_w, int src_h, 
                const uint32_t* src, bool flip_x, bool flip_y);
```

By using negative values and passing it to an image operation (ex: a blit operation), the result will naturally be flipped without having to actually flip the image. It'll end up being "drawn flipped", so to speak, just as with the case of using OGL with a negative scaling transformation matrix.